# Recreate Econ Table

Tags: tables

[image]

Could someone please help recreate this table from Petrin (2002) with two differences:

- 4 instead of 5 columns i.e. Variable, OLS Logit, Instrumental Variable Logit and Random Coefficients
- With part C. called Other Coefficients (designed the same as part A.)

Thank you so very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please read the [introductory material](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for this site. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. Questions of the form "Please do this for me" are typically ignored.

Comment: Regarding "Could someone please help recreate this table": Do you really expect someone else to copy numbers and texts froma screenshot in order to create teh table for you or did you already try something but the output just doesn't look right? If the latter is the case, please show what you tried so far and ask a specific question.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you're trying to copy. Is it the structure, the font for the numbers, the font used for text, the exact size of the asterisks, the minute indentation of the table notes below the tabled, the overall width of the tabular material, the uppercase lettering of 'TABLE', the small-caps rendering of the remainder of the caption, the line break between 'TABLE 4' and the remainder of the caption? All of the above? Something else? Please be specific.

Comment: Could you please suggest the font and camel case style used for the table caption?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=sc, labelsep=newline}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{A Test Caption Text}
\end{table}
\end{document}`